# I can't find GoogleCloudMessaging class

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) class, but I can't find how I can add some library to use it.

I added Android `SDK\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist\gsm.jar`, but this jar didn't include GoogleCloudMessaging class. Where is it? What should I add to my project? Thanks.

Comment: Did u have GCM plugin Installed in ur ADT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GoogleCloudMessaging` class is located in Google Play Services library. Download it, include on your project with gsm.jar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this instruction: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.